# A problem i'm facing concerning if and elif fonction

Tags: python, if-statement

the cost of renting a car per day is 40 dollars.
if the days you rented the car in is equal or superior to 7 you get 50 dollars off the total cost
if the days you rented the car in is equal or superior to 3 you get 20 dollars off the total cost
You can't get both reductions at the same time.............

```
days=raw_input()
cost= 40*days
if days>=7:
 cost-=50
elif days>=3 and days<7:
 cost-=20 
print(cost)
```

i was expecting to find the total cost ofthe car's rent .

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: yup thanks buran .  i corrected it     cost= 40*int(days)

Answer (score 0):

I simply tried this code

```
days=8
cost= 40*days
if days>=7:
cost-=50
elif days>=3 and days<7:
cost-=20 
print(cost)
```

And other options of Days. the code is working alright

Comment: you defined days as integer 8 in the code itself       i didn't   so what fixed my problem is cost=40*int(days)

Comment: Maybe be more specific next time ?, u didnt even show us the error